# how do I place relativelayout under another relativelayout using xml

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to place a relativelayout  under another (with recyclerview in it) within an activity layout container.

What I'd like to get is to have the action bar, then below a relativelayout with header (showing a spacer and 2 textviews), and below again another relativelayout that will host cards from a recyclerview.
This is the image of the wanted design:

[image: desired design]

What I get instead is this:

[image: result design]

I am using the following xml (but tried many others)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/category_detail_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_header_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spacer"
            android:background="#66555555"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_header_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/sub_header_title"
            android:background="#66555555"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_container"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="@dimen/default_spacing_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/default_spacing_small" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to put the second RelativeLayout nested as a child of the first one with no luck.

The Android Studio preview shows the design well formatted but after build the card list overlaps the header. Well formatted apart from the unknown line/constraint I do not know how to remove. It constraints the second relativelayout to the top.

[image: android studio design preview]

What am I missing?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you using NestedScroll, If you don't want to use scroll than you have to manage with Weight.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you say. 
I am not sue I need NestesScroll. As far as I understand NestedScroll is used whenever you need to scroll 2 lists or objects in the same activity, but I do not need to. 
Just one list needs scrolling. The header is fixed 

What I need is a Header, and a scroll list below the Header.
i didn't think it was so difficult. I must be missing something

Answer (score 1):

Use `FrameLayout` instead of `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

Or try with `LinearLayout`